# Find two points 30 degrees away from a line and a set distance away from and endpoint.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

You are given a line $\overline{PQ}$ specified only by the coordinates of its start and end points, which are $P$ and $Q$ respectively. Find the two points, $A$ and $B$, such that you can draw two segments $\overline{QA}$ and $\overline{QB}$ that make a 30$^\circ$ angle with $\overline{PQ}$ and are a specified distance $x$ away from endpoint $Q$. In the end, you should have an equilateral $\triangle QAB$.

I'm trying to implement something like this within my code, so if there is no clean general solution, but rather, different yet very similar solutions that address different cases, that would also work.

I've tried finding trigonometric solution (using cosines, sines, and arctan) as well as a more geometric solution using the properties of a 30-60-90 triangle (find where $\overline{AB}$ would intersect $\overline{PQ}$ then finding the coordinates of $A$ and $B$ from there, knowing their distances away from that intersection), yet all seemed to devolve into a copious number of computations, and so I'm wondering if there is a simpler solution I'm overlooking.

Comment: Let me clarify- if you had a trig. or geometry solution you could write the code for it?

Comment: I haven't gone through this, but I strongly suspect all of the approaches (which must be effectively equivalent, of course) yield conceptually simple but arithmetically messy results.

Comment: @nickalh Yes. I have an implicit coordinate system in my current GUI and I'm essentially trying to draw those points onto the canvas, so it would just be a lot of lines of code, especially because, in that sense, I don't have any real equations, just coordinate points.

Answer (score 1):

You want $\triangle QAB$ to be an equilateral triangle of side $x$ such that the infinite ray from $Q$ through $P$ bisects the angle of the triangle at $Q.$

Therefore the infinite ray from $Q$ through $P$ passes through the midpoint $M$ of the side $AB$, and the distance from $Q$ to $M$ is $\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ of the length of the side of the triangle.
Moreover, the side $AB$ is perpendicular to $QP.$

---

Here's a simple way to realize this in coordinates using vectors.

First, normalize the vector from $Q$ to $P$ so you have a unit vector $\hat p$
pointing in the direction of $\vec{QP}.$

Find the point $M = Q + \left(\frac{\sqrt3}{2} x\right)\hat p.$

Find a unit vector $\hat n$ perpendicular to $\hat p.$
You can do this by swapping the two coordinates of $\hat p$ and then negating one of them.

Let $A = M + \left(\frac12 x\right)\hat n.$
Let $B = M - \left(\frac12 x\right)\hat n.$

---

An alternative formulation: Let $p$ be the vector from $Q$ to $P.$
Let $n$ be a vector equal in magnitude to $p,$ orthogonal to $p.$
(You can get $n$ by swapping the coordinates of $p$ and then negating one coordinate.)

Let $a = \left(\sqrt3\right) p + n.$
Let $b = \left(\sqrt3\right) p - n.$

Scale each of the vectors $a$ and $b$ to length $x.$
Let $a'$ and $b'$ be the scaled vectors.

Let $A = Q + a'$ and $B = Q + b'.$

Comment: Great conceptual solutions. Unfortunately, I'm not completely sure how to apply this in code given as I'm working solely with coordinates.

Comment: Either alternative is all coordinates from start to finish. The vectors have coordinates too.

Comment: For example, a vector from the point `(Q_x,Q_y)` to `(P_x,P_y)` has $x$ coordinate `P_x-Q_x`, similarly with the $y$ coordinate. The notation $(\sqrt3)p$ is just another vector which you get by multiplying each coordinate of $p$ by $\sqrt3$. And so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Shift the coordinate system, if $Q = (x_q, y_q)$, shift it to Q' = (0, 0)
This makes $P = (x_p, y_p)$, into $P'= (x'_p, y'_p) = (x_p-x_q, y_p - y_q) $

**The angle from PQ to positive x axis is
$\theta = arctan \frac{y'_p}{x'_p}$
Add a check, x<0, if you need + $\pi$

$A'= (x'_A, y'_A) = (x cos (\theta-30), x sin (\theta-30))$ and

$B'= (x'_B, y'_B) = (x cos (\theta + 30), x sin (\theta + 30) ) $

Finally, reverse the translation or shift back to your desired coordinate system.

$A= (x'_A+ x_Q, y'_A+y_Q)$ and $B= (x'_B + x_Q, y'_B + y_Q) $

Note 1: As always make your trig. functions match your degrees given in the question.  Or use $\frac{pi}{6}$ and radians.

Note 2: x is the length of AQ = length of BQ, and not related to $x_q, x_p$ or $x'_p$.

Note 3:** If your environment or a library supports, matrix multiplication, the arctan step is optional.  You can rotate the coordinates system with an appropriate matrix multiplication.  It's called change of basis.  But a rotation will only work if centered around the origin.

Note 4: If so desired, I believe the translation or shifts can also be accomplished with matrix addition and subtraction for the reverse.

Comment: I came about a very similar solution but wouldn't quite get it to work in the code itself and it's very possible I made some error. I'll try this out when I have time, thanks.

Comment: I invite others to check this for mistakes or validate it.

Comment: Once you wade through all the details, possibly after brushing up on some details (ex. to normalize a vector is to find the unit, length 1 vector pointing in the same direction) and convert each vector to xy coordinates, David's solution may be simpler to code.